# Is there a "global" setting for Do Not Disturb on iOS devices?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

As the title suggests, I would like to set DND on one device that will affect the other. I have looked through Settings on both devices but haven't found anything (unless it is a deeply hidden setting). A bonus would be if this would also affect my MBP.
MBP: macOS 10.15.4
iPhone & iPad: iOS 13.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no one setting that applies to all devices.

Each device has its own Do Not Disturb feature, as explained [here](https://support.apple.com/HT204321) for iOS devices and [here](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-do-not-disturb-mchl999b7c1a/mac) for macOS devices.

Comment: Note however that enabling/disabling Do not Disturb on an Apple Watch will also enable/disable it on the connected iPhone, and vice versa.